# How to break from objx(data).each(function(item) iteration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to break from `objx(data).each(function(item)` iteration when a certain condition is met.

My Json string is below:

```
var data= [{"field1": "0","field2": "2"},{"field1": "7","field2": "2"},{"field1": "1","field2": "5"}];
```

Here is a my code:

```
function iterate(){
                objx(data).each(function(item){
                 if(item.field1 == "7"){
                   //doing some job;
                   return; 
                  }
                 alert("after if is executed");// this alert coming inspite of giving 
                });                            // return in if block
             }
```

i think the return is only enabling it to come out of function but not from the loop. i dont want this unnecessary iteration once my condition is met and job is done.
can anyone suggest how to come out of this each loop?

Answer (score 2):

```
return false;
```

Returning false breaks out of the each function.

Comment: no problem.  please mark this as answered if it satisfies your question.

Comment: see http://code.google.com/p/objx/wiki/each?ts=1341574845&updated=each#continue_alternative

Answer (score 2):

To exit the jquery each loop

```
function iterate(){ 
    objx(data).each(function(item){ 
        if(item.field1 == "7"){ 
            //to stop the loop here
            return false; // here - will exit the each loop 
        }
    }); 
}
```